# Display two fields on the same bar chart using Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, charts, visualization, kibana

I want to do a chart like this:

[image: The chart I want to generate]

So I have two fields “rest_of_the_world” and “china” that I want to display on the same bar chart. The Y axis is supposed to be the number of document that contain a X value (a count).

So for instance I have 150 documents that have “1996” in the field “rest_of_the_world” and "15 documents that has “1996” in the field “china”.

Is it possible to do such a chart with Kibana? And will it be possible to plot the difference between the two?

Comment: You can do that with timelion

Answer (score 1):

It's an old question, but I was searching for a tutorial or something to plot this kind of chart. Here is what you have to do:

```
-Go to [Visualize] menu, then click on the [ + ] button to add a [Vertical bar] chart
-Choose your index
-On the Metrics panel expand the [Y-Axis] options (witch selected type should be Count)
-Change the [Aggregation] to Sum
-In [Field] choose the index field/column representing the number of documents

-On the Buckets panel expand [X-Axis] options
-Put on [Aggregation] the field/colum representing the year 
 (or, if there are many records with date choose {Date histogram}, select the 
 field with that date and choose {Yearly} in the [Interval])

-Then click on the [Add sub-buckets] button on the bottom of Buckets panel
-On [Sub Aggregations] choose Terms
-On [Field] choose the field/column representing the place of document
```

And that's it!

Answer (score 0):

Customize the sub-aggregations:
To create bars for "rest_of_the_world" and "china", you can add a sub-aggregation for each field.
Add a '**Metric**' for each field and select the appropriate aggregation operation (for example, 'Average', 'Sum', etc.).